# Auto refresh the activity

Tags: android

In my application I have a activity that displays contents from internet..... I just want to know how can I auto refresh the activity.....

Please suggest and provide some code block if possible.

Comment: What exactly do you want to `refresh`? Do you want to redraw it?

Comment: I want to auto reload the activity, without clicking on any button....

Comment: Are you using Adapter to display content in your activity ????

Comment: At the very least post all the code you have to date, and describe the exact problem you have.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this one, it works well :)

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        this.mHandler = new Handler();

        this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable,5000);


    }//onCreate

    private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()

        {
            Toast.makeText(refresh.this,"in runnable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            refresh.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 5000);            
        }

    };//runnable


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(m_Runnable);
        finish();

    }
/*Above method needs to be there otherwise activity will be updating itself again and again even if the activity is paused i.e. back button or home button is pressed*/
```

Comment: It worked well! Thanks! Syed described the code for onCreate() method and variables mHandler and m_Runnable (for this last one, he created the method). Other people following this tip, use both parts of code and do not forget to create the variable mHandler as a Activity variable (Handler mHandler;), too!

Comment: Hi @Syed what is the variable of refresh

Answer (score 15):

You can use handler to do a loop process, like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable refresh;
```

In the first call time:

```
refresh = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Do something
        handler.postDelayed(refresh, 5000);
    }
};
handler.post(refresh);
```

Since you cannot call a non-final variable inside an annonymous class, you will have to declare `refresh` in the containing class.

Comment: I love Handlers.  That's all I wanted to say.

Comment: @param What problem do you meet?

Comment: @ W.N. I not sure, but I never worked with handlers.... It would be very nice if you could explain exactly how to use this....

Comment: @param This is NOT code for refresh the web browser. It's for doing ANYTHING after an amount of time (in my example, 5000 = 5second). Add any code you want at '// Do something' code line, for example reload the web browser.

Answer (score 5):

This code for If you want first create the view and after that refreshing page at specified time span then use following code.(here mention refreshing rate is 20 seconds)
It Works Fine and Automatic refresh in every 20 seconds.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Handler mHandler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.mHandler = new Handler();
        m_Runnable.run();

}
    private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()

        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"in runnable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            MainActivity.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable,20000);            
        }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider purchasing "[The Busy Coder's Guide to Advanced Android Development](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/)", to read in particular Chapter 13, "Advanced Service Patterns".  The source code for this chapter [is available on Github](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), with this handy introduction:

> CWAC Wakeful: Staying Awake At Work
>
> The recommended pattern for Android's equivalent to cron jobs and Windows
> scheduled tasks is to use AlarmManager. This works well when coupled with an
> IntentService, as the service will do its work on a background thread and shut
> down when there is no more work to do.

It goes over coupling `AlarmManager` with an `IntentSerivce`.  This is far more complex than using a Handler, but packaging data services in a `Service` is a good practice and actually compulsory if you want to share data between different applications.

If you don't know how to use services, consider purchasing [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](http://commonsware.com/Android/).  It "comes with" the book I mentioned earlier.  I bought all of them yesterday and they're a veritable goldmine.