# How to refresh activity on create? how to refresh activity

Tags: android

I follow this stackoverflow link [Auto refresh the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134832/auto-refresh-the-activity) which refresh activity every 5 second i want to refresh activity once only on create not every 5 second waht do i do?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  this.mHandler = new Handler();

  this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable,5000);

}//onCreate

private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable()
{
  public void run()
  {
    Toast.makeText(refresh.this,"in runnable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    refresh.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 5000);            
  }

};//runnable
```

Comment: I dont really know what you mean by refresh. Also I dont know if you want it to refresh 5 sec. after the create or with the calling of create.

Comment: i take picture from  gallery using intent when intent finisg this activity not refresh and show pictures until i go back and come again on this activity

Comment: So your idea is to actually refresh every five seconds? Not only once?

Comment: no no not every 5 second just once on Oncreate

Comment: U can write the logic in onstart() or onresume() methods.

Comment: But your app gets refreshed OnCreate... Since it is reloaded. I srsly dont get. Check out this site for the activity lifecycle.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you described your actual problem in the comments, i'll answer this here.

You shouldn't refresh you app every 5 seconds. You should react to the intents result.

Solution No 1 (ActivityForResult approach)

This is how you do it:

```
private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 100;
```

Start the Intent

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

This part is called on a result. And you should refresh your activity in this method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case SELECT_PHOTO:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
To make it clear: What happens is, that you create your activity. Call your intent. Your activity is getting paused `onPause()` and after the picking it gets resumed `onResume()`. So if you want to refresh your activity after it was paused. You write this behaviour in the `onResume()` Method.
But still if you are starting an Intent for some result. You would use the above method to add the result to your activity.

Solution No 2 (general approach)

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Refresh here
}
```