# Reload GPS Position Android without push a button

Tags: android, gps

I get the GPS Position if i start the activity from my Service class. But i want to reload it without push a button. does anybody know how it works ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you look at this post, which refreshes the Activity after a given interval: 
[Auto refresh the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134832/auto-refresh-the-activity)

Comment: thanks, for the hint with the handler. It works very well

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a service schedulated? It will exec your principal service at a scheduled time.

See this: [Define and consume local service](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html#scehdulingservices)